# \s and whitespace in vim

Tags: vim, whitespace

```
:%s/^\s\{4\}//g
```

It can replace four blank spaces at the beginning of a line with zero blank space.
We draw the conclusion that `\s`=whitespace  `\{4\}`=four times.

```
:%s/^\s\{4\}/  /g
```

It can replace four blank spaces at the beginning of a line with two blank spaces.
And it is obvious that `\s\{2\}`=two white spaces.

```
:%s/^\s\{4\}/\s\{2\}/g
```

Why the command can't replace four blank spaces at the beginning of a line with two blank spaces?
Why the command means that to replace four blank spaces at the beginning of a line with  s{2} ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\s` stands for any whitespace character like tab or space. There is no way for vim to know which character you want to use in substitution.

To replace with same character, use `:%s/^\(\s\)\{4\}/\1\1/g`

Comment: new idea,more smarter  way than others.

Answer (score 3):

What makes sense in the pattern part of a `s/.../.../` doesn't necessarily make sense in the replacement part.  The pattern is a (Vim's idea of) regular expression.  The replacement is a string with some special shortcuts.  Very different beasts.

Answer (score 2):

Intuitively, if you can buy an apple for a dollar, why can't you eat a dollar, and you can eat an apple?

Technically, the replace command, `[range]s[ubstitute]/pattern/replacement/[flags] [count]`, interprets `pattern` and `replacement` differently. The pattern is a regular expression (`:help pattern`); the replacement is not (`:help sub-replace-special`). `\s` is whitespace in a regular expression, but not in a replacement.